# Set style for div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, cross-browser, styles

I need to make my application run on all browsers and I have a div for which I set the css class in Javascript using the syntax

```
 divNew.className = "highlightItem";
```

It works ok on IE, but when it comes to Firefox, Opera and Chrome it's not working at all. I have also tried other versions such as

```
 var theDiv = document.getElementById(divNew);
 theDiv.setAttribute("class", "highlightItem");
 theDiv.setAttribute("className", "highlightItem");
```

with no success. Setting all the attributes through style isn't working either.

Are there any other ways of setting the css class for a div so that it works on the above mentioned browsers? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's the content of `divNew` in the second example?

Comment: Works for me on Google Chrome: http://tinkerbin.com/swXMlipL . Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Can you show that here http://jsfiddle.net ?  first and second attempts to set styles should work fine

Answer (score 2):

On this line:

```
 var theDiv = document.getElementById(divNew);
```

You need the id of your div there as a string:

```
var theDiv = document.getElementById("my-div-ID");
```

Other than that it should work.

If you want to save yourself time with cross-browser issues look into [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) - you would just do:

```
$("#my-div-ID").addClass("highlightItem");
```